# Passing String file path from child window to opener in asp.net: how to prevent the back slash to be removed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tried to pass a string value from a child window to the text box in a opened window. The value is:

```
string fileName = @"C:\aaa.txt";
```

Once the above value has been passed into the parent window, the back slash `\` is automatically removed, and `fileName` has the value `C:aaa.txt`

What is the reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason behind this issue?

The "\" is an [escape character](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) in JavaScript.  This language is used to pass the fileName from the child to parent window.

> The backslash escape character turns special characters into string
>   characters

```
Code     Outputs
\'         single quote
\"         double quote
\\         backslash
\n         new line
\r         carriage return
\t         tab
\b         backspace
\f         form feed
```

The example below demonstrates the use of the escape character on the x variable.  [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ariight/bcmrb3pb/%23share&togetherjs=lR5R6wlBAy).

```
<script>
var x = 'C\:aaa';
alert(x);
</script>
```

To prevent this from happening, double slashes `"\\"` will be required to escape the single backslash.

```
string fileName = @"C:\\aaa.txt";
```

Comment: Hi @Chaminda if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.